# Does there is a mathematical proof of this fact?

Tags: prime-numbers

The question is related to this page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brun%27s_theorem) (in the section: **Asymptotic bounds on twin primes**) on twin primes.

I am interested on the line where the author says: *Brun's constant could be an irrational number only if there are infinitely many twin primes.*

My **question** is: Does there is a mathematical proof of this fact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are only finitely many pairs of twin primes, Brun's constant is a finite sum of rational numbers, which is rational.

If there are infinitely many pairs of twin primes, Brun's constant can be irrational or rational.